# Error compiling hector exploration node. Could not find hector_map_tools

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm new to ROS. I want to use hector exploration planner in my project which consists on a robot which must explore as many rooms as possible in a house. The robot doesn't have a map of the house. As I'm still learning the ropes, I want to use a package to do autonomous exploration and I found hector exploration.

I have downloaded https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation (branch catkin) unzip it in /home/myName/catkin_ws/src/hector_navigation-catkin/
Then I cd to /home/myName/catkin_ws and I executed catkin_make but it doesn't work and I don't know how to fixed. I already had other compilation problems but I could fix them. Now I have the following error:

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "hector_map_tools" with any of the following names:

hector_map_toolsConfig.cmake

hector_map_tools-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "hector_map_tools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "hector_map_tools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "hector_map_tools" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hector_navigation-catkin/hector_elevation_visualization/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225587/error-compiling-hector-exploration-node.-could-not-find-hector_map_tools/) by [HangukUMA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25544/hangukuma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_map_tools](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/tree/catkin/hector_map_tools) is part of hector_slam. You should be able to satisfy this dependency by installing it from .debs:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam
```

Alternatively, you could add https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git ti your workspace and compile it from source.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1